# Making an API call if response is SUCCESS in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I have a method based on which I bring response as `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE`. So on `SUCCESS` status I want to make an API call which is `https://testabc.com/xxxxx/pmp/xxx`

Below is that method.

```
public void IsSiteIPLValidorNot(string NEID, out string response)
    {
        response = ""; string status = string.Empty;
        response = CommonUser.GET_IPL_STATUS_ON_NEID(NEID);

        if (response == "SUCCESS")
        {
            // call api here
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Site is not IPL');", true);
        }
    }
```

Do let me know how can be done in simple and easy way.

**EDIT**

The details of API is here.

```
url --location 'https://testabc.com/xxxx/pmp/xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
"A6_NEID": "INGJJMGRPVTGNB0001PMPAA6001",
"Azimuth": 10,
"Height": 26,
"VerticalBeamwidthTilt": 2,
"VerticalBeamwidth": 30,
"HorizantalBeam": 65,
"DistanceofCone": 500,
"SourceSystem": "MANUAL"
}'
```

Comment: Have you research for [`HtttpClient.SendAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.8.1_) or [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#basic-usage)?

Comment: @YongShun: I am new to this, so don't have much idea about it.!! Please suggest how to proceed with this ?

Comment: At least you should provide more info, what is the HTTP method? GET, POST or etc. What is the value you tried to send? In Query string, form data, request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a great documentation about [making HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient), but I'll also provide you an example for your case:

```
// Please, consider using IHttpClientFactory, instantiating a new handler for each request can lead to socket exhaustion 
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    // Think of this as the base url for all your api calls
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testabc.com")
};

var content = new
{
    A6_NEID = "INGJJMGRPVTGNB0001PMPAA6001",
    Azimuth = 10,
    Height = 26,
    VerticalBeamwidthTilt = 2,
    VerticalBeamwidth = 30,
    HorizantalBeam = 65,
    DistanceofCone = 500,
    SourceSystem = "MANUAL"
};

// Send the request (automatically serializes the content as json and adds the content-type header)
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/xxxx/pmp/xxx", content);

// This will throw an exception if the response is not successful
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// If you need to read the response, you can:
// Read as string
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// Or, deserialize to a class
var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<YourClass>();
// Etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient() class to make an API call. Something like that:

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://testabc.com/xxxxx/pmp/xxx");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// Deserialize the JSON response
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

return data;
```